# NSTask spawns top process. How to extract data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

**EDIT 1**

This code is currently printing to the console. What I would like to do is get the data in a string (**and stop the data going to the console**) so I can parse it for specific information. I hope my question is clear. Please ask for clarification if needed :)

---

**EDIT 2**

Another alternative could be to print it to a file and then I could read from that file afterwards. Just don't want it printing to the console :)

---

Hello Lovely Intelligent Computer People!

Any help with this would be great.

So far I'm using NSTask to spawn a process:

```
NSTask *top_task;
top_task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[top_task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/top"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-s", @"1",@"-l",@"3600",@"-stats",@"pid,cpu,time,command", nil];
[top_task setArguments: arguments];


NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];

[top_task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[top_task launch];
```

Now, how do I grab the resulting information, let us say, in the form of an NSString?

Thanks for all and any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To launch your timer, you would want to do something like this:

```
NSTask *topTask = [NSTask new];
[topTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/top"];
[topTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-s", @"1", @"-l", @"3600", @"-stats", @"pid,cpu,time,command", nil]];

NSPipe *outputPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[topTask setStandardOutput:outputPipe];
[topTask launch];
```

So far, the code is really similar to what you've written, but you're going to have to add some more code to it. In order to get data every time `top` updates, you have add this one line of code to the end:

```
[[outuputPipe fileHandleForReading] readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

That will send you an `NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification` (if you register for it) every time `top` updates with output, and you can query the notification object for the incoming data and convert it to an NSString like this:

```
NSString *outputString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

---

You can read up on this in the [NSFileHandle documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and [Interacting With the Operating System](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OperatingSystem/OperatingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000058i).

Answer (score 1):

You set up a pipe for standard input for no apparent reason.  I'd think you would want a pipe for standard output, and then read from that.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it like that:

```
[top_task waitUntilExit];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[file readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: Oh, right. You have to add this: [top_task setStandardOutput: top_pipe];

Comment: Is 'waitUntilExit' waiting for the task to finish? If so, isn't that a bit odd since it is iterating every second for an hour? It's still not printing, by the way.

Comment: That's right: for never terminating apps like top this will not work. Use itaiferber's solution then. However if you use some different app that does exit, this may be a simpler solution.